# React - Add a class only when an item is clicked

Tags: reactjs, onclick, classname

I have got one stateless component like this:

```
    import React from 'react';
    import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

    const Panel = (props) => {
      return(
        <div
          className={props.className}
          onClick={props.onClick}>
          <p>{props.firstChild}</p>
          <p>{props.secondChild}</p>
          <p>{props.thirdChild}</p>
        </div>
      )
    }

    Panel.propTypes = {
      onClick: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
      className:PropTypes.any.isRequired,
      firstChild: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
      secondChild: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
      thirdChild: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    };

    export default Panel
```

And I have my Class component like this:

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import Panel from './panel'

    class ImageGallery extends Component {
      constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.state = {
          open: false,
        }
      }

      toggleOpen = () => {
        console.log('hi')
        this.setState({
          open: !this.state.open
        })
      }

      render() {
        return (
          <div className="panels">
            <Panel
              firstChild="Hey"
              secondChild="Let's"
              thirdChild="Talk"
              onClick={this.toggleOpen}
              className={this.state.open ? "panel panel1 open open-active " : "panel panel1"}
            />
            <Panel
              firstChild="Hey"
              secondChild="Give"
              thirdChild="Me"
              onClick={this.toggleOpen}
              className={this.state.open ? "panel panel2 open open-active " : "panel panel2"}
            />
          </div>
        )
      };
    }

    export default ImageGallery;
```

onClick on one `Panel`component want that this one adds the `open` and `open-active` classes to my item.
At the moment onClock on one item both are opening, but I want both to be handled separately.

I am not sure how to do this the cleanest way, using state and classes.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interestingly, I just coded something very similar to this in my application this morning.

I did it sort of like this (if you only want one panel to open at a time): You can see this working in a sandbox here. https://codesandbox.io/s/mow9nyj958

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Panel from './panel'

class ImageGallery extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      openPanel: undefined,
    }
  }

  toggleOpen = (panelNumber) => {
    console.log('hi')
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      openPanel: (prevState.openPanel === panelNumber) ? undefined : panelNumber 
    }))
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="panels">
        <Panel
          firstChild="Hey"
          secondChild="Let's"
          thirdChild="Talk"
          onClick={() => this.toggleOpen(1)}
          className={`panel panel1 ${(this.state.openPanel === 1) ? "open open-active" : ""}`}
        />
        <Panel
          firstChild="Hey"
          secondChild="Give"
          thirdChild="Me"
          onClick={() => this.toggleOpen(2)}
          className={`panel panel1 ${(this.state.openPanel === 2) ? "open open-active" : ""}`}
        />
      </div>
    )
  };
}

export default ImageGallery;
```

But I assume you would want to be able to open both panels at once, so you could do something like this.

```
class ImageGallery extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      panel1Open: false,
      panel2Open: false
    }
  }

  toggleOpen = (panelNumber) => {
    console.log('hi')
    this.setState(prevState => {
      const key = `panel${panelNumber}Open`;
      return { [key]: !prevState[key] }
    })
  } 
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="panels">
        <Panel
          firstChild="Hey"
          secondChild="Let's"
          thirdChild="Talk"
          onClick={() => this.toggleOpen(1)}
          className={`panel panel1 ${this.state.panel1Open ? "open open-active" : ""}`}
        />
        <Panel
          firstChild="Hey"
          secondChild="Give"
          thirdChild="Me"
          onClick={() => this.toggleOpen(2)}
          className={`panel panel1 ${this.state.panel2Open ? "open open-active" : ""}`}
        />
      </div>
    )
  };
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, funny you had the same challenge ! I tried to implement your solution unfortunately nothing happens. I only need to open one panel at the same time, so I would rather go with your first proposition. Still searching how to resolve that...

Comment: Here i created a codesandbox so you can have a better view on it https://codesandbox.io/s/3yw7r9o16q

Comment: Hi @Fabian, here's a sandbox with the first proposition working. https://codesandbox.io/s/mow9nyj958  I'm sorry, in my answer above I had a mistake that broke the code. I've fixed it above now, and you can see it properly in the sandox

Comment: thanks so much this time its working as expected !! Thanks for taking the time to hep, really appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

You would need separate value to keep track of those panels, something like below. I haven't test the code, but should look like this.

```
 import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import Panel from './panel'

    class ImageGallery extends Component {
      constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.state = {
          panel1: {
            open: false
          },
          panel2: {
            open: false
          }
        }
      }

      toggleOpen = (key) => {
        console.log('hi')
        this.setState({
          [key]: {
            open: !this.state[key].open
          }
        })
      }

      render() {
        return (
          <div className="panels">
            <Panel
              firstChild="Hey"
              secondChild="Let's"
              thirdChild="Talk"
              onClick={() => this.toggleOpen('panel1')}
              className={this.state.open ? "panel panel1 open open-active " : "panel panel1"}
            />
            <Panel
              firstChild="Hey"
              secondChild="Give"
              thirdChild="Me"
              onClick={() => this.toggleOpen('panel2')}
              className={this.state.open ? "panel panel2 open open-active " : "panel panel2"}
            />
          </div>
        )
      };
    }

    export default ImageGallery;
```

additionally, for easier management of className, I suggest you to use [classnames](https://github.com/JedWatson/classnames) package.

Comment: I tried your solution but unfortunately nothing happens ! I am not really getting why...

Comment: sin your code is not runnable it's hard for ppl to tell whats happening, consider to build a minimal example using codesandbox.io

Comment: You are totally right, I should have done that since the begining. Here you can find a link to the code and you will see the behavior. https://codesandbox.io/s/3yw7r9o16q

Answer (score 0):

Add a name to each one of your `<Panel />` components:

```
<Panel
name="Foo"
isOpen={this.state.fooOpen}
...
/>
<Panel
name="Bar"
isOpen={this.state.barOpen}
...
/>
```

In your handler use code like this:

```
toggleOpen = event => {
    if(event.target.name === "Foo") {
        this.setState({fooOpen: true})
    } else {
        this.setState({barOpen: true})
    }
}
```

Make sure that in your Panel component you are passing the name down to the element that you are calling the handler from.